# degree of the splitting field of $x^{16}-1$ over $\Bbb F_9$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

> Compute $[E:\Bbb F_9]$ where $E/\Bbb F_9$ is a splitting field of $x^{16}-1$ over $\Bbb F_9$.

I want to find $\text{Gal}(E/\Bbb F_9)$. Since $E/\Bbb F_9$ is a cyclic extension, it suffices to compute the above degree. What I've done so far is that $x^{16}-1 = (x^8+1)(x^8-1)$ and as $\Bbb F_9$ is a splitting field of $x^9-x\in \Bbb F_3[x]$, $x^8-1$ splits in $\Bbb F_9$. And $x^8+1 = (x^4+2x^2+2)(x^4+x^2+2)$. I don't know how to get further. Could you give any hint?

Comment: The field $\Bbb{F}_9$ has a square root of $-1$, call it $i$. We also have
$$x^8+1=(x^4-i)(x^4+i).$$ Because factorization is unique, we must have non-trivial gcds between these quartic factors and those over $\Bbb{F}_3$ that you found. Anyway, the simplest route to the splitting field is to find the one that contains the needed roots of unity. Endorsing lhf's answer (I have posted embarrassinigly many similar ones already).

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Find the splitting field over $\Bbb F_3$. Prove that $x^4+2x^2+2$ and $x^4+x^2+2$ are irreducible over $\Bbb F_3$.

Alternatively, since $z^8+1=0$ implies that $z$ has order $16$ in $E^\times$, consider the smallest $n$ such that $16$ divides $3^n-1$.